# Should I index all columns from MySQL table in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I just got my hands on ElasticSearch, and I immediately got confused whether should I put all the columns of a table in MySQL to an index in ES.

My goal of using ES is only to enhance the search ability of my app.
And I have a `vehicle` table for example, which contains dozens of fields, like `category, brand, thumbnail` etc., and another table called `models` which also contains dozens of fields containing the model specifications, like `sku, engine, horsepower, color` etc. Assuming my clients would only search for `brand and color`, how should I structure the index in ES?

I imagine that if I index(store) only the fields what my clients may be searching, then I would have to query MySQL for extra info to display in the app. And if I store all the fields, then isn't it too much in case of redundancy? I mean, two tables with over one hundred fields combined into one single index, but only couple of them are used for search? (I haven't figure out how to index relationships in ES yet, so just assuming).

Comment: Index the fields in ES which you intend to query.  But what does MySQL have to do with your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MySQL is the main data source. ES is only for search. What I mean in my questions is, if field B will not be searched, should I put it in ES as well? Because I have to display both field A & B in the search results.

Comment: No...if you are really only searching by `A`, then the search should return `B` and all other fields.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So are you saying that I should put all the fields in ES? Won't that impact the performance and take two much space? Consider the amount of data if it's for logging records, rather than vehicles.